# Calculate inverse of a non-square matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

I'm pretty new to the **R** language and trying to find out how you can calculate the inverse of a matrix that isn't square. (non-square? irregular? I'm unsure of the correct terminology).

From my book and a quick google search, (see [source](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html)), I've found you can use `solve(a)` to find the inverse of a matrix **if** `a` is square.

The matrix I have created is, and from what I understand, not square:

```
  > matX<-matrix(c(rep(1, 8),2,3,4,0,6,4,3,7,-2,-4,3,5,7,8,9,11), nrow=8, ncol=3);
  > matX

       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    2   -2
  [2,]    1    3   -4
  [3,]    1    4    3
  [4,]    1    0    5
  [5,]    1    6    7
  [6,]    1    4    8
  [7,]    1    3    9
  [8,]    1    7   11
  >
```

Is there a function for solving a matrix of this size or will I have to do something to each element? as the `solve()` function gives this error:

```
  Error in solve.default(matX) : 'a' (8 x 3) must be square
```

The calculation I'm trying to achieve from the above matrix is: `(matX'matX)^-1`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Referring to your last line, try: `solve(t(matX) %*% matX)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ginv** `ginv` in the MASS package will give the generalized inverse of a matrix.  Premultiplying the original matrix by it will give the identity:

```
library(MASS)
inv <- ginv(matX)

# test it out
inv %*% matX
##               [,1]         [,2]          [,3]
## [1,]  1.000000e+00 6.661338e-16  4.440892e-15
## [2,] -8.326673e-17 1.000000e+00 -1.110223e-15
## [3,]  6.938894e-17 8.326673e-17  1.000000e+00
```

As suggested in the comments this can be displayed in a nicer way using `zapsmall`:

```
zapsmall(inv %*% matX)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    0    0
## [2,]    0    1    0
## [3,]    0    0    1
```

The inverse of `matX'matX` is now:

```
tcrossprod(inv)
##              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
## [1,]  0.513763935 -0.104219636 -0.002371406
## [2,] -0.104219636  0.038700372 -0.007798748
## [3,] -0.002371406 -0.007798748  0.006625269
```

**solve** however, if you aim is to calculate the inverse of `matX'matX` you don't need it in the first place.  This does not involve MASS:

```
solve(crossprod(matX))
##              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
## [1,]  0.513763935 -0.104219636 -0.002371406
## [2,] -0.104219636  0.038700372 -0.007798748
## [3,] -0.002371406 -0.007798748  0.006625269
```

**svd** The `svd` could also be used and similarly does not require MASS:

```
with(svd(matX), v %*% diag(1/d^2) %*% t(v))
##              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
## [1,]  0.513763935 -0.104219636 -0.002371406
## [2,] -0.104219636  0.038700372 -0.007798748
## [3,] -0.002371406 -0.007798748  0.006625269
```

ADDED some additional info.

Comment: `zapsmall` might be nice for showing the results of `inv %*% matX` more cleanly ...

Comment: Oh cool :D Thanks for taking the time to answer :D That's great.

Comment: For the svd solution, why square the diagonal matrix? diag(1/d^2)

Comment: @user1143669, Please read the second last line of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what's called a "[Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)". Here's a function `exp.mat`that will do this for you. There is also an example outlining it's use [here](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2012/03/exponentiation-of-matrix-including.html).

#### `exp.mat()`:

```
#The exp.mat function performs can calculate the pseudoinverse of a matrix (EXP=-1)
#and other exponents of matrices, such as square roots (EXP=0.5) or square root of 
#its inverse (EXP=-0.5). 
#The function arguments are a matrix (MAT), an exponent (EXP), and a tolerance
#level for non-zero singular values.
exp.mat<-function(MAT, EXP, tol=NULL){
    MAT <- as.matrix(MAT)
    matdim <- dim(MAT)
    if(is.null(tol)){
        tol=min(1e-7, .Machine$double.eps*max(matdim)*max(MAT))
    }
    if(matdim[1]>=matdim[2]){ 
        svd1 <- svd(MAT)
        keep <- which(svd1$d > tol)
        res <- t(svd1$u[,keep]%*%diag(svd1$d[keep]^EXP, nrow=length(keep))%*%t(svd1$v[,keep]))
    }
    if(matdim[1]<matdim[2]){ 
        svd1 <- svd(t(MAT))
        keep <- which(svd1$d > tol)
        res <- svd1$u[,keep]%*%diag(svd1$d[keep]^EXP, nrow=length(keep))%*%t(svd1$v[,keep])
    }
    return(res)
}
```

#### example of use:

```
source("exp.mat.R")
X <- matrix(c(rep(1, 8),2,3,4,0,6,4,3,7,-2,-4,3,5,7,8,9,11), nrow=8, ncol=3)
iX <- exp.mat(X, -1)
zapsmall(iX %*% X) # results in identity matrix
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your time. Is there a specific package I need to use to use the function you state above?

Comment: Oh wait, I guess you need to create that function yourself in your program?

Comment: @Reanimation - Your welcome. No, you can just load the function as is (i.e. pass the function code to your R environment). If you prefer to load a package rather than `source`this function, a similar function (`pseudoinverse`) can also be found in the package `corpcor`. The advantage to the `exp.mat` function is that it can also take other exponential values (e.g. `EXP=-0.5`).

Comment: `MASS::ginv` also implements a pseudo-inverse, and comes with a standard R installation ...

Comment: @BenBolker - Cheers. I can't believe I didn't know about `ginv` - thanks for pointing it out.